# convert emailsettings from web.config to appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Im trying to convert the following lines in a .net 4.7 web.config file:

> ```
> <mailSettings> 
>     <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
>         <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\folder"/>
>     </smtp> 
> </mailSettings>
> ```

to a core 2 appsettings.json configuration, IF it is possible something like:

```
{
    "mailSettings": {
    "DeliveryMethod ": "SpecifiedPickupDirectory",
    "pickupDirectoryLocation": "C:\folder"
     }
}
```

But im not sure if this is possible in core 2, or is something that cant be done by the configuration like it was done in .net 4.7+. Any feedback/tips/workarounds appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're a bit off - try:

```
{
  "mailSettings": {
    "smtp": {
      "deliveryMethod": "SpecifiedPickupDirectory",
      "specifiedPickupDirectory": { 
         "pickupDirectoryLocation": "C:\\folder" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a couple of things before you can be done by configuration..

Step 1: Parse to Json

```
{
 "mailSettings": {
    "smtp": {
        "specifiedPickupDirectory": {
            "_pickupDirectoryLocation": "C:\\folder"
        },
        "_deliveryMethod": "SpecifiedPickupDirectory"
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2: On Startup search and get your mailing configurations

```
var mailSettings = Configuration.GetSection("mailSettings");
```

Step 3: Put the mail config to your class with something like this..

```
services.Configure<MailingOptions>(options =>
{
    options.smtp = mailSettings["smtp"];
});
```

Take a look to .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1